# HTML is not rendering - Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm making a simple blog app for my site and fetching posts from array. When I try to use HTML tags in the **posts** I'm seeing they are not rendering, *rest of page is ok*.

**Posts:**

```
{"post_id":1, 
 "post_title":"Title", 
 "post_body":"This is a test text. <b> I'm testing HTML.</b> "} ....
```

**Output** in the page is :

```
This is a test text. <b> I'm testing HTML.</b>
```

**Server-side:**

var hbs = require('hbs');

```
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);

app.get('/post/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.render('post_theme',
    {post, title etc...});
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Page</title>
  <!-- font css -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/semantic/build/packaged/css/semantic.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  <!-- js -->
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/semantic/build/packaged/javascript/semantic.js"></script>


</head>
<body id="home">
 <div class="ui menu" >
....
</div>

        <h3 class="ui header">{{title}}</h3>
        <p>{{body}}</p>

</body>


</html>
```

Why HTML is not rendering?

*(Actually I'm not sure this is Express question, I'm new to Web development.)*

---

**Solution:**

Based on  **Andrew Counts** answer I used three brackets and problem is solved. `{{{...}}}`

Comment: did you create the project by using the cli interface? i.e. 'express install xxxx' ??

Comment: Yes, I created it with express-io framework from command line.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  First you say that HTML is not rendering, but then you say that the rest of the page is ok.  EVERYTHING that renders in a browser is HTML, so you need to be a bit more specific about what you expect to render, and what actually is.... you are certainly getting SOME HTML, unless a blank white screen is what you consider ok.

Comment: ok based on your edit, I assume what you mean is that you have HTML tags in your data model, and you want them rendered as HTML instead of as plain text.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my confusing question.

Comment: which template engine are you using?  looks like EJS maybe?

Comment: I'm using `hbs` engine.

Comment: Try using triple curly braces to access the raw html, `{{{body}}}`

Comment: It was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In handlebars templates, HTML codes are escaped from variables automatically, in order to ensure that values stored are not able to break the page code flow.  if you are SURE that you do want to output the HTML stored in a variable, and that it will not break your page, you can instruct Handlebars to not escape the HTML, either by using triple braces `{{{ }}}`, or by storing the value as type 'Handlebars.SafeString`.

http://handlebarsjs.com/